# C rand() dice issue

Tags: c, random, modulus

I'm new to C and I'm reading a book about it. I just came across the `rand()` function. The book states that using `rand()` returns a random number from 0 to 32767. It also states that you can narrow the random numbers by using `%` (modulus operator) to do so.
Here is an example: the following expression puts a random number from 1 to 6 in the variable `dice`

```
dice = (rand() % 5) + 1;
```

I'm unable to get a remainder of 5 as any number from 0 to 33767 `% 5` is equal to 0 to 4, but never 5.

Shouldn't it be `% 6` in the above statement instead?

For example, if I choose randomly a number between 0 and 32767, let's say 75, then:

```
75 % 5 == 0
76 % 5 == 1
77 % 5 == 2
78 % 5 == 3
79 % 5 == 4
80 % 5 == 0
Etc.
```

So regardless of the random number between 0 and 32767, the remainder will never be 5, so it will not be possible to get a 6 number for the dice (as per the above statement).

Not sure if you will understand what I mean but your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? You answered it yourself.

Comment: `rand()` doesn't return a number from 0 to 32767. Read the manual first

Comment: In C % is actually remainder not a modulo operator.

Comment: You're right. It's a simple error by the author.

Answer (score 1):

`dice = (rand() % 5) + 1;`

This will generate a random number between 1 to 5, inclusive, as you have analyzed. The `% 5` in the book is probably just a typo. To get 1 to 6 it needs to be `% 6`.

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to understand how modulo (%) works. If you have say 10 and divide it by 5 you get 2 with a remainder of 0, hence the 10 % 5. The possible range of remainders you would get when you mod(modulo) 5 is 0 - 4. Remember that the possible remainders would can get when you divide by x if from 0 to x-1. So in your case with the dice program you need numbers from the range of 1 to 6 (the faces of a die) hence you would mod 6 and add 1 to this number for give the necessary shift. `(rand() % 6) + 1`

Comment: Thank you all... So this is what I thought... % 5 is probably a typo in the book. Thanks again for confirming this with me.